# Aptana Studio 3 and PDT

Tags: xdebug, eclipse-pdt, aptana

For three days I tried to install Aptana 3 with PDT.
I like the auto suggestion in Aptana. I need the xdebug feature from PDT.
At this moment it works only when I have two separate installations.

I have tried to install Aptana studio 3 and as plugin the pdt
and PDT all in one, and then Aptana.

No matter what installation variation I use, after I bring both programs together, the autosuggesion feature from aptana stops to work properly.
in css block and in php block.

How can I fix this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You first need to make sure that the editor you are using is the right one.
PDT brings with it the WST plugin, which also provides support for other web languages, and that may also contribute to the situation you are at.

Both environments provide support for some of the common web file types (*.php, *.html etc), and you may have to set the default editor for each of the file type in the eclipse preferences ('File Associations' and 'Content Type' settings).

You can do a right-click on a file and select the 'Open With' option to see which editor is opening it by default, and end try and change it for that specific file.

For PHP, I suggest that you stick to one of the two plugins: 
If you go for PDT, make sure that the project was created using the PDT project creation wizard, and that the files are being opened with the PDT editor.
If you go for the Aptana PHP support, make sure that the project was created using the Aptana PHP project wizard, and that the files are opened with the Aptana PHP Editor (this editor will use the Aptana Theme).

For CSS - Make sure you get the file opened with the Aptana CSS editor (it will have the Aptana Theme).

Beside all of that, there is always the chance that there is a bug there. You can check the error log and see if you get anything new and suspicious there when you load eclipse/studio.
If you have Aptana installed, that would be accessible through the Help menu.

Hope that will get you closer to a solution :)